# How to run single process for multiple values in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, parallel-processing, task

I need to run single process for list of symbols. So I have a list of symbols like AAPL, FB, QQQ, MSFT, IBM and also I have a function which contains logic of calculations for given symbol. So perform my this logic I am using Task.

```
List<string> symbolList = new List<string>() {"AAPL","QQQ","FB","MSFT","IBM"};
Task[] taskArray = new Task[symbolList.Count];
for(int i=0; i<taskArray.Length; i++)
{
   taskArray[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {
          criteriaEvalution.Evaluate(finalArray, false, new List<parseObj>(), ref builder, symbolList.IndexOf(i));
       });
}
Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
```

So when I am running this code then it's showing me error like

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Error is showing on line:

```
criteriaEvalution.Evaluate(finalArray, false, new List<parseObj>(), ref builder, symbolList.IndexOf(i));
```

where I am going to pass symbol name to the function.

So please can I get a solution for this?
I have checked on google for this it's saying for the index is out of range. I have checked by set debugger but I not understand how to check it for task regions.

Comment: symbolList.IndexOf(i) will always return -1(I don't know how you can write this without any error from IDE), It should be Index of somthing you stored in the list, like symbolList.IndexOf("AAPL") this will return 0 and  symbolList.IndexOf("QQQ") this will return 1

Comment: if I use symbolList[i] then also it's showing same error.

Comment: Can I see full code of the criteriaEvalution class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Parallel.Foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.2) can do this. Here an example how to:

```
public static void DoIt(string a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> symbolList = new List<string>() { "AAPL", "QQQ", "FB", "MSFT", "IBM" };
    Parallel.ForEach(symbolList, a => DoIt(a));
}
```

You can control the call by using `ParallelOptions`:

```
ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 };
Parallel.ForEach(symbolList, options, a => DoIt(a));
```

Comment: It's worse to mention that Parallel lib has heavy CPU consumption and is not recommended to use for server-side code

Comment: I need to handle this process on server side. And also there will be multiple symbols in list.

Comment: @OlegI will parallel.foreach consume lots of cpu uses ?

Comment: @Ankit yes, it is not recommended for instance for web apps. When there are a lot of concurrent users

Comment: so in this scenario which method I need to use for concurrent process. can you suggest me for it ?

Comment: @Ankit, first of all, try to use thread safe collection, if multiple threads are going to access one instance.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would use the concurrent collection `ConcurrentBag` in this case(if you write into the collection). Concurrent collections are going to lock the instance when multiple threads are about to access it. Also, I would suggest using `Task.WhenAll` with `await` keyword. `Task.WaitAll` can create a deadlock. So here is a sample you can try out:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    var symbolList = new ConcurrentBag<string> { "AAPL", "QQQ", "FB", "MSFT", "IBM" };
    var taskArray = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var s in symbolList)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Process(s);
        });

        taskArray.Add(task);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(taskArray);
}
```

Comment: The `ConcurrentBag` is a very specialized container. In must cases you'll get better performance with a `ConcurrentQueue` or `ConcurrentStack`, and when enumerating the collection the ordering will be more intuitive.

Comment: This won't fix it - you're not capturing `s` in the lambda.

Comment: @Enigmativity actually [it does](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/), from C# version 5 and later. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - It explains nicely the issue that the OP has though. Maybe he's using an older version of the framework?

Comment: @Enigmativity I believe that there is a bug in his code. He uses `symbolList.IndexOf(i)` that returns -1, instead of the correct  `symbolList[i]`.

Comment: It feels like we are not trying to solve his real problem anymore. The thing is, there were other issues with the posted code, thus different answers were posted

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should replace:

```
symbolList.IndexOf(i)
```

...with:

```
symbolList[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you've got illegal code (`symbolList.IndexOf(i)` should probably be `symbolList[i]`) the issue you're facing is that you're not capturing the loop variable before you call the lambda.

Here's the simple fix:

```
List<string> symbolList = new List<string>() { "AAPL", "QQQ", "FB", "MSFT", "IBM" };
Task[] taskArray = new Task[symbolList.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++)
{
    string symbol = symbolList[i];
    taskArray[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        criteriaEvalution.Evaluate(finalArray, false, new List<parseObj>(), ref builder, symbol);
    });
}
Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
```

Note the line `string symbol = symbolList[i];` before you start the task.

If you don't do this the loop finishes before the tasks start and then `i` is equal to `taskArray.Length` and hence you get the "Index was out of range" error.

The other this I'd suggest is you should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
List<string> symbolList = new List<string>() { "AAPL", "QQQ", "FB", "MSFT", "IBM" };

var query =
    from symbol in symbolList.ToObservable()
    from e in Observable.Start(() =>
        criteriaEvalution.Evaluate(finalArray, false, new List<parseObj>(), ref builder, symbol))
    select e;

query.ToArray().Wait();
```

Much simpler and cleaner than tasks. Then you can use LINQ operators on the results too.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to install a huge dependency to your project in order to solve this simple case.

Comment: @OlegI - Why **huge** dependency? I agree it's a dependency, but huge?

Comment: For me, it seemed overkill since it is possible to solve it in an easier way, without adding external dependencies. But anyways thanks for the answer, nice to see other options. Could help readers